# Service and Activity accessing shared data

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have an Activity that starts a service. I would like the service to have access 1 of the Activity's member variables(a boolean). I have implemented a getBoolean() method in the Activity, but how do I instantiate the Activity in the service for it to access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SharedPreferences to  save  data in activity and yu can access it in service
in  OnStartCommand method when you start a service

SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("MYPREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sharedPref.getBoolean("flag",false);

Comment: Yup I ended up using a SharedPreferences. Just thought that accessing it directly would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Instead, use a broadcast receiver or shared preferences.

Example using broadcast receiver -

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    boolean mActivityBoolean;

    BooleanReceiver mReceiver;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mReceiver = new BooleanReceiver();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
                mReceiver, new IntentFilter("activityBooleanIntent")
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public class BooleanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            mActivityBoolean = intent.getBooleanExtra("activityBoolean", false);
        }
    }
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    void someMethodThatSendsABooloean(boolean trueOrFalse) {
        .....
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("activityBooleanIntent");
        intent.putExtra("activityBoolean", trueOrFalse);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```